# compiler not accepting ternary operator's use

Tags: c++, vector, ternary-operator

I have a *char vector* **arr** and a *vector* **arrnode** which has its elements as *node*. Following is the code:

```
struct node
{
    int min;
    int sum;
};

vector<char> arr;
char c;

for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    cin >> c;
    arr.push_back(c);

}

vector<node> arrnode;
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
  /* if(arr[j]=='(')
       arrnode.push_back({1,1});
       else
      arrnode.push_back({-1,-1});*/

      arrnode.push_back( ( ( arr[j]=='(' ) ? {1,1} : {-1,-1} ) );

}
```

This code gives the following error for the line where ternary operator is used.

```
prog.cpp:68:49: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘{’ token
prog.cpp:68:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
```

However, the if-else part(which is commented) makes the code work fine. What am I missing?
Thanks in advance and sorry for the shabby title of the question :)

Comment: Try to add () in between
`arrnode.push_back(((arr[j]=='(')?({1,1}):({-1,-1})));`
Hope this help

Comment: @SatishBejgum No, it doesn't. Still a compiler error.

Comment: What you can do instead is `arr[j] == '(') ? (node){1,1} : (node){-1,-1}`, but I'm not sure it's standard (reminds me to C99 compound literals, and C99 isn't C++...)

Comment: Also, to @OP: **Use whitespace. *Please!***

Comment: Why not take the hint and use `if` instead?

Comment: @nijansen...I did...just wanted to know why first one didn't work

Comment: Try this
`node a = {1,1};
     node b = {-1,-1};
     arrnode.push_back((arr[j]=='(') ? a : b);`

Comment: It is looking for an expression and `{}` are not in themselves an expression, if I understand correctly. I think section `8.5.4` of the standard is what you need, it covers where list initialization can take place and the ternary expression is not listed.

Comment: Some one answer the question

Comment: What's wrong with using `if`? It's easier to read, and people can actually follow what the code is meant to do.

Comment: @MatsPetersson In a case like this, `if` is very definitely _less_ readable: the important thing is the `push_back`, not the condition.

Answer (score 4):

So using `gcc` the error you see will look something like so:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
```

It is expecting an expression but `{}`s are not an expression, they are just usable for list initialization in some places as specified by section `8.5.4` of the [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), which says:

> ... List-initialization can be used
>
> — as the initializer in a variable definition (8.5)
>
> — as the initializer in a new expression (5.3.4)
>
> — in a return statement (6.6.3)
>
> ....

It does not list the `conditional operator`. As others have said an alternative is to use an `if` statement. Although as James points out this may not be the ideal substitution, so if you feel that the `conditional operator` works better in your context then as James suggests just use the following:

```
arrnode.push_back( arr[j] == '(' ? node( 1, 1 ) : node( -1, -1 ) );
```

Comment: And others have pointed out wrong.  Whether `if` or a conditional operator is better depends on context; in this case, the important thing is the `push_back` (unconditional), so that should be put in evidence, rather than the reader having to analyze two branches, only to discover that they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JamesKanze That is a fair argument, I amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax doesn't allow it.  And how could it: what is the type
of `{ 1, 1 }`?  (The compiler must determine the types in
a conditional expression.)

Rather than being fancy, why not just write:

```
arrnode.push_back( arr[j] == '(' ? node( 1, 1 ) : node( -1, -1 ) );
```

It's clearer when you state the type explicitly, not only for
the compiler, but for the human reader.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the ternary operator the compile can't tell the type, it's just an initialiser, so you need

```
arrnode.push_back((arr[j]=='(')? node({1,1}) : node({-1,-1}));
```

Your construct is not the same as the `if`, it's more like

```
if(arr[j]=='(')
  x={1,1};
else
  x={-1,-1};
arrnode.push_back(x);
```

`x` has no type.

Answer (score 0):

In C you would write:

```
 arrnode.push_back( ( ( arr[j]=='(' ) ? (node){1,1} : (node){-1,-1} ) );
```

But in C++ "Compound literals" are not allowed so you can write:

```
 arrnode.push_back( ( ( arr[j]=='(' ) ? node{1,1} : node{-1,-1} ) );
```